# D3.js Treemap - Hide elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I developed a treemap for visualizing softwares starting from this example `http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/`. Now I need to hide elements from it and recompute the layout. What is the best way to do that?

Current status:
[image: Visualization]

Comment: Filter the data you want to hide.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I already have the id of the element I want to hide, the problem is how to hide that element and recompute the layout accordingly

Comment: You filter that element out of the data, then pass the filtered data (i.e. without the element you want to hide) to the layout.

Comment: By filtering it out of the data you mean for example removing a given element from the children of its parent? Or there's another way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.